# function not returning JSON property value - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I've created a database on Couch.db and I am using the couch.GET method in order to retrieve document data. I created a test function that would retrieve the value of the "name" object and output the results through console.log.

```
function sendDB() {
    couch.get(dbName, viewUrl).then(
        function(data, headers, status){
            console.log(data.data.rows[0].value.name);
        }
    )
}

sendDB();
```

In the above function, the output is 'John Doe' as it should be. The problem arises when I try and return the value of `data.data.rows[0].value.name`

```
function sendDB() {
    couch.get(dbName, viewUrl).then(
        function(data, headers, status){
            DB = JSON.stringify(data.data.rows[0].value.name);
            return DB;
        }
    )
}

console.log(sendDB());
```

In the above function, the console reads 'undefined' and I am quite confused. I need to use the returned value in other functions so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but you've got a problem with your function arguments, `function(data, headers, status)`. That function is being passed to `then` so it will only have a single argument, just like with any other promise. This particular API passes an object containing 3 properties, `data`, `header` and `status`. Some `node-couchdb` examples use destructuring, such as `function({data, headers, status})`, to pull that object apart. Note the braces, which are missing in your code. If you have an old version of Node it may not support destructuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the promise from `sendDB()`. Currently there is no `return` to the outer function.

Since the promise is asynchronous you need to use `then()` chained to the function call

```
function sendDB() {
   // return the promise
   return couch.get(dbName, viewUrl).then(
        function(data, headers, status){
            DB = JSON.stringify(data.data.rows[0].value.name);
            return DB;
        }
    )
}
sendDB().then(function(DB){
    console.log(DB);
});
```

Comment: I put the return statement into the outer function and called the function as you wrote but I got an error saying 'cannot read property 'then' of undefined'. I'm a beginner so I apologize if my question is poor. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, my bad for not seeing the return written on the outside of the couch.get statement